# Expression must have intergral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, enums

So I'm working on the file save system of my game and I tried making a simple string that will be generated for saving the files correctly but I keep getting this error

```
string file = "ChunkData/" + x + "." + y + ".chunk";
```

I keep getting the error where the `"."` and I don't understand why. I have tried changing it to be something other than `"."` like so:

```
string file = "ChunkData/" + x + "test" + y + ".chunk";
```

But that did nothing. I don't understand why I keep getting this error. What is really interesting is that in Visual Studio in the error section it claims that '+' cannot add two pointers which confuses me even more because neither x nor y are pointers, they are integers.

Comment: What are the types of `x` and `y`? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu ints... like i said in the last sentence

Answer (score 0):

While you can concatenate `std::string`´s with `+`, you have 3 char arrays and 2 integers here, and no `std::string` at all. Only the result, after adding everything, is converted to a string, that´s to late for the `+`. Your just adding memory addresses and your integers together, that makes no sense.

Do something like that:

```
string file = "ChunkData/" + tostring(x) + "." + tostring(y) + ".chunk";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string file = str::string("ChunkData/") + std::to_string() +
              "." + std::to_string(y) + ".chunk";
```